# Web based solution for Android app (SQLite) and Website Database (SQL) Sync

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

This topic has been raised a few times but even after searching and going through suggestions I haven't found a solution.

I have a PHP based website and an Android app that has to use the same database. The database is for an objective type test. The questions are created on the web using an admin panel.

The Android app needs to work offline so there is a need for one time sync when internet is available.

I have created a table in PHPMyAdmin called "database version". The Android app checks the database version using a web service. If the the version number is different it should be able to download the latest version of the database of the website and store it locally for offline access.

One of the suggestions I've come across is to convert the .sql database into .sqlite and give the download link of .sqlite to the Android app. However, converting .sql database to .sqlite using PHP doesn't seem to be easy. I've come across some shell script method but with no knowledge about that it probably doesn't work for me.

So, I'm looking for way to make sure the Android app can use the same database of the website but only require internet connection for syncing otherwise the app will work offline.

Would appreciate if I could get some directions and advise as to how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sure If I would choose a solution that "replaces" the database when your app gets back online. I think I would build a database on the Android (SQLite), and synced with the Webdatabase (MySQL) row by row, by comparing datastamps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using SQLite on the Android app. For the initial (first time user download of the .apk) download I have used a SQL to SQLite converter software to manually convert the database and then store in the .apk package. But once the database changes after the user has installed the app then how do I sync over-the-air? You've mentioned sync the web database (MySQL) row by row by comparing data stamps. Would appreciate if you'd share some more insight about this approach. Thanks!

Comment: You have an "last_updated" on all rows on both SQLite (phone) and MySQL (Web). Depending on how you data can be changed you need to do some checks. If mysql data never changes unless it comes from the phone, you can simple get the max(last_update) from mysql and only select rows newer than this from your SQLite table, and send them to the web database. If you can have changes on the web, at the same time as offline SQLite can change you need to have a "master".

Comment: Thank you, that does provide some more clarity.  All changes will be made to the web (SQL) database and Android app needs to update it's SQLite database accordingly. You mentioned "send them to the web database". In my case I need to send the changes to the Android database. How can this be accomplished? What would be the best practice to do this?

Comment: Actually, You would have to fetch it. Use a AsyncTask thread object not to lock the GUI thread as you do the http request from your android to your webserver. Search google "asynctask httpclient" and you will find code examples.